# add text to a header of a fasta file

Tags: r, bash, awk, str-replace, fasta

I have a fasta files (txt) of a genome, something like:

```
$ cat Strain-01.faa
>IMEHDJCA_03186 Serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2
MEFKHRFIDGSRYQRIFVIGDIHGKLALLQDTLKRVDFHGERDLLISVGDLIDRGPDSVG
VLDYYQTHDWFEAVMGNHEWMMVNALDAQNKLERSEKEAYFIKIWHRNGCEWSQNL
>IMEHDJCA_03187 Serine transporter
MKESRETLNFSDTLPTETWTKHDTHWVLSLFGTAVGAGILFLPINLGIGGFWPLVLLALL
AFPMTFWGHRALARFVLSSKQADADFTDVVEEHFGAKAGRLISLLYFLSIFPILLIYGVG
>IMEHDJCA_03189 hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD
```

I want to add an extra ID based in a list within a file.txt.

```
$ cat file.txt
ID      Gene        Strain-01       Strain-02       Strain-03
ID_01   pphB        IMEHDJCA_03186  DIBHEKPI_01648  LLMDBGDK_00598
ID_02   group_1001  IMEHDJCA_03187  DIBHEKPI_01635  LLMDBGDK_00611
ID_03   group_1002  IMEHDJCA_03189  DIBHEKPI_01628  LLMDBGDK_00616
```

For example for the fasta `Strain-01.faa` file has the `IMEHDJCA_03186` id corresponding to the `Strain-01`, so I want to add the `ID_01` number of the column ID (from `file.txt`) to the header of the sequence, something like:

- `ID_01` corresponds to `IMEHDJCA_03186`
- `ID_02` corresponds to `IMEHDJCA_03187`
- `ID_03` corresponds to `IMEHDJCA_03189`

The result will be like:

```
$cat Strain-01_edited.faa
>ID_01 IMEHDJCA_03186 Serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2
MEFKHRFIDGSRYQRIFVIGDIHGKLALLQDTLKRVDFHGERDLLISVGDLIDRGPDSVG
VLDYYQTHDWFEAVMGNHEWMMVNALDAQNKLERSEKEAYFIKIWHRNGCEWSQNL
>ID_02 IMEHDJCA_03187 Serine transporter
MKESRETLNFSDTLPTETWTKHDTHWVLSLFGTAVGAGILFLPINLGIGGFWPLVLLALL
AFPMTFWGHRALARFVLSSKQADADFTDVVEEHFGAKAGRLISLLYFLSIFPILLIYGVG
>ID_03 IMEHDJCA_03189 hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD
```

I just want to add a ID code of the `file.txt` to the header of the fasta file.

Any idea to do this ? in `bash` or `R`, or any other way ?

Thanks so much

Comment: `bash` or any other shell would be a terrible choice for this or any other text manipulation, see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). I expect you meant `Unix tool` (e.g. awk, sed, etc.) rather than `bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The R way is a good bit longer, but may be a good option if you like to see what you're doing in a REPL.

```r
# read in file and split into groups, each starting with a line like "> ..."
strain <- readLines(con = 'Strain-01.faa')
strain <- split(strain, cumsum(grepl('^>', strain)))

# extract ids from line 1 of each group
ids <- sapply(strain, function(x) gsub('^>(\\w+).*', '\\1', x[1]))

# read in ID lookup table and match to the extracted IDs
id_lkp <- read.table('file.txt', header = TRUE)
id_num <- with(id_lkp, ID[match(ids, Strain.01)])

# for each group, append the id after > to the first line
for(i in seq_along(strain)){
  strain[[i]][1] <- sub('^>(\\w+)', paste0('>', id_num[i], ' \\1'), strain[[i]][1])
}

# write to output file
writeLines(unlist(strain), file('output.txt'))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Now output.txt looks like:

```
>ID_01 IMEHDJCA_03186 Serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2
MEFKHRFIDGSRYQRIFVIGDIHGKLALLQDTLKRVDFHGERDLLISVGDLIDRGPDSVG
VLDYYQTHDWFEAVMGNHEWMMVNALDAQNKLERSEKEAYFIKIWHRNGCEWSQNL
>ID_02 IMEHDJCA_03187 Serine transporter
MKESRETLNFSDTLPTETWTKHDTHWVLSLFGTAVGAGILFLPINLGIGGFWPLVLLALL
AFPMTFWGHRALARFVLSSKQADADFTDVVEEHFGAKAGRLISLLYFLSIFPILLIYGVG
>ID_03 IMEHDJCA_03189 hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD
```

Comment: This was a fast solution and worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE #2:** Eliminating specific strain (name) processing by `awk`:

- we'll load all possible strain/ID mappings into `awk`
- this will allow processing of any `*.faa` file without a need to know the strain name
- this will allow processing of a `*.faa` file with a mix of strains (no idea if this is something OP has to address)
- reduces complexity of `awk` code (compared to **UPDATE #1**) at the expense of additional memory for more `id[]` array entries

Sample data (mix of strains in first field):

```
# for this (nonsensical?) file the first 3 blocks include a strain
# from each of the 3 columns (of strain names) from file.txt; the
# 4th block contains a nonsensical strain that doesn't exist in
# file.txt (ie, 4th line should not see an insertion of a ID value)

$ cat Strain-mixed.faa
>IMEHDJCA_03186 Serine transporter
MKESRETLNFSDTLPTETWTKHDTHWVLSLFGTAVGAGILFLPINLGIGGFWPLVLLALL
AFPMTFWGHRALARFVLSSKQADADFTDVVEEHFGAKAGRLISLLYFLSIFPILLIYGVG
>DIBHEKPI_01635 Serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2
MEFKHRFIDGSRYQRIFVIGDIHGKLALLQDTLKRVDFHGERDLLISVGDLIDRGPDSVG
VLDYYQTHDWFEAVMGNHEWMMVNALDAQNKLERSEKEAYFIKIWHRNGCEWSQNL
>LLMDBGDK_00616 hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD
>NO_MATCH hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD
```

New `awk` code to load all strains into `id[]` array:

```
awk '
NR==1   { next }                           # skip 1st line of 1st file
FNR==NR { for (i=3; i<=NF; i++)            # for rest of 1st file load id[] with ...
              id[$i]=$1                    # all strain/ID combos
          next
        }
/^>/    {                                   # for 2nd file, if 1st column is ">"
          ndx=substr($1,2)                  # strip off ">"
          if ( ndx in id )                  # if 1st field (sans ">") is an index in id[] then ...
             ( $1=">" id[ndx] " " ndx )     # rewrite 1st field to include our id[] value
        }
1                                           # print current line (of 2nd file)
' file.txt Strain-mixed.faa
```

This generates:

```
>ID_01 IMEHDJCA_03186 Serine transporter
MKESRETLNFSDTLPTETWTKHDTHWVLSLFGTAVGAGILFLPINLGIGGFWPLVLLALL
AFPMTFWGHRALARFVLSSKQADADFTDVVEEHFGAKAGRLISLLYFLSIFPILLIYGVG
>ID_02 DIBHEKPI_01635 Serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2
MEFKHRFIDGSRYQRIFVIGDIHGKLALLQDTLKRVDFHGERDLLISVGDLIDRGPDSVG
VLDYYQTHDWFEAVMGNHEWMMVNALDAQNKLERSEKEAYFIKIWHRNGCEWSQNL
>ID_03 LLMDBGDK_00616 hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD
>NO_MATCH hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD
```

**NOTE:** This latest update will perform ID insertions for all of the rows in the `Strain-{01,02}.faa` files (see **UPDATE #1**, below).

---

---

**UPDATE #1:** Expanding the original answer to address (I think) Paul Hodges' question about generalizing the answer to support a variable strain name:

- dynamically determine which column of strains to use from `file.txt`
- dynamically process the matching `<strain>.faa` file

Sample data:

```
$ cat Strain-01.faa
>IMEHDJCA_03186 Serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2
MEFKHRFIDGSRYQRIFVIGDIHGKLALLQDTLKRVDFHGERDLLISVGDLIDRGPDSVG
VLDYYQTHDWFEAVMGNHEWMMVNALDAQNKLERSEKEAYFIKIWHRNGCEWSQNL
>IMEHDJCA_03187 Serine transporter
MKESRETLNFSDTLPTETWTKHDTHWVLSLFGTAVGAGILFLPINLGIGGFWPLVLLALL
AFPMTFWGHRALARFVLSSKQADADFTDVVEEHFGAKAGRLISLLYFLSIFPILLIYGVG
>IMEHDJCA_03189 hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD

# for this next file I simply copied data from OP's Strain-01.faa and
# modified the initial field for blocks 1 & 3; net result is we should
# see 2 of the blocks receive insertions of ID values

$ cat Strain-02.faa
>DIBHEKPI_01635 Serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2
MEFKHRFIDGSRYQRIFVIGDIHGKLALLQDTLKRVDFHGERDLLISVGDLIDRGPDSVG
VLDYYQTHDWFEAVMGNHEWMMVNALDAQNKLERSEKEAYFIKIWHRNGCEWSQNL
>IMEHDJCA_03187 Serine transporter
MKESRETLNFSDTLPTETWTKHDTHWVLSLFGTAVGAGILFLPINLGIGGFWPLVLLALL
AFPMTFWGHRALARFVLSSKQADADFTDVVEEHFGAKAGRLISLLYFLSIFPILLIYGVG
>DIBHEKPI_01648 hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD

$ cat Strain-XX.faa
cat: Strain-XX.faa: No such file or directory
```

With a few modifications to the original `awk` answer, and wrapping in a (`bash`) `for` loop for processing different strains:

```
for strain in Strain-01 Strain-02 Strain-XX
do
    printf "\n############### ${strain} / ${strain}.faa\n\n"

    awk -v strain="${strain}" '                 # pass bash variable in as awk variable (same name)

    NR==1   { for (i=3; i<=NF; i++)             # 1st row of 1st file, look for matching strain name
                  { if ( $i == strain )         # if we find a match then ...
                       { strain_ndx=i           # make note of the column and ...
                         next                   # skip to next line from 1st file
                       }
                  }

              # if we got here we did not find a matching strain name so 
              # print a message and exit from our awk script 

              print "Unable to locate entry for "strain" in "FILENAME". Aborting."
              exit
            }

    FNR==NR { id[$(strain_ndx)]=$1              # for rest of 1st file build array of ids
              next
            }

    /^>/    {                                   # for 2nd file, if 1st column is ">"
              ndx=substr($1,2)                  # strip off ">"
              if ( ndx in id )                  # if 1st field (sans ">") is an index in id[] then ...
                 ( $1=">" id[ndx] " " ndx )     # rewrite 1st field to include our id[] value
            }
    1                                           # print current line (of 2nd file)
    ' file.txt "${strain}.faa"
done
```

This generates:

```
############### Strain-01 / Strain-01.faa

>ID_01 IMEHDJCA_03186 Serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2
MEFKHRFIDGSRYQRIFVIGDIHGKLALLQDTLKRVDFHGERDLLISVGDLIDRGPDSVG
VLDYYQTHDWFEAVMGNHEWMMVNALDAQNKLERSEKEAYFIKIWHRNGCEWSQNL
>ID_02 IMEHDJCA_03187 Serine transporter
MKESRETLNFSDTLPTETWTKHDTHWVLSLFGTAVGAGILFLPINLGIGGFWPLVLLALL
AFPMTFWGHRALARFVLSSKQADADFTDVVEEHFGAKAGRLISLLYFLSIFPILLIYGVG
>ID_03 IMEHDJCA_03189 hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD

############### Strain-02 / Strain-02.faa

>ID_02 DIBHEKPI_01635 Serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2
MEFKHRFIDGSRYQRIFVIGDIHGKLALLQDTLKRVDFHGERDLLISVGDLIDRGPDSVG
VLDYYQTHDWFEAVMGNHEWMMVNALDAQNKLERSEKEAYFIKIWHRNGCEWSQNL
>IMEHDJCA_03187 Serine transporter
MKESRETLNFSDTLPTETWTKHDTHWVLSLFGTAVGAGILFLPINLGIGGFWPLVLLALL
AFPMTFWGHRALARFVLSSKQADADFTDVVEEHFGAKAGRLISLLYFLSIFPILLIYGVG
>ID_01 DIBHEKPI_01648 hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD

############### Strain-XX / Strain-XX.faa

Unable to locate entry for Strain-XX in file.txt. Aborting.
```

---

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
FNR==NR { id[$3]=$1 ; next }                # for 1st file build array of ids
/^>/    {                                   # for 2nd file, if 1st column is ">"
          ndx=substr($1,2)                  # strip off ">"
          if ( ndx in id )                  # if 1st field (sans ">") is an index in id[] then ...
             ( $1=">" id[ndx] " " ndx )     # rewrite 1st field to include our id[] value
        }
1                                           # print current line (of 2nd file)
' file.txt fasta.dat
```

For the given sample data this generates:

```
>ID_01 IMEHDJCA_03186 Serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2
MEFKHRFIDGSRYQRIFVIGDIHGKLALLQDTLKRVDFHGERDLLISVGDLIDRGPDSVG
VLDYYQTHDWFEAVMGNHEWMMVNALDAQNKLERSEKEAYFIKIWHRNGCEWSQNL
>ID_02 IMEHDJCA_03187 Serine transporter
MKESRETLNFSDTLPTETWTKHDTHWVLSLFGTAVGAGILFLPINLGIGGFWPLVLLALL
AFPMTFWGHRALARFVLSSKQADADFTDVVEEHFGAKAGRLISLLYFLSIFPILLIYGVG
>ID_03 IMEHDJCA_03189 hypothetical protein
MNNQRHGITFGIERIGSQTILVFKATGTLTHQDYQAIAPVLEAALAGINRQQMNMLADIS
EFSGWEPRAAWDDFQLGLKIGFSVNKVAVYGDKNWQELAAKVGSWFISGEMKSFGD
```

Comment: Nice. Can you expand it to match strains by column and filename in one pass?

Comment: @PaulHodges : I think these updates address your question/suggestion ... ?

Comment: That should help the OP. I was hoping to see it all in the `awk` script, but don't waste time entertaining me when the problem is solved, lol ;)